# Can an EMI filter ferrite cores on data cables or ferrite beads be used as forward transformer?

Tags: ferrite-bead, forward

Is there some difference in magnetic properties between ferrite cores of EMI filters on data cables/ ferrite beads and forward transformer cores?

Can EMI filters cores/ ferrite beads be used as forward transformer?

[image]

Comment: Have you done any calculations on it? Core material for EMI filters tend to be high Al-high loss. For a transformer you want low loss. But can it? Yes.

Comment: I didn’t make any calculatiom since I don’t have datasheet. I tried to wind it and connect to application. And it seems the transformer overloads my circuit  with even no load on secondary and 120 turns on primary( that should be enough).

Comment: these ferrites are typically rather lossy at 10 MHz and up. At usual transformer frequencies they'd be fine.. But they have huge permeance, so they saturate very quickly, or have a low Vs rating in other words. You must have a load to not saturate it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but it might not matter much for your purposes.

Assuming, by "forward transformer", you mean "transformer in a forward converter circuit", and not, say, some kind of precocious robot. :)

More importantly, the shape isn't very easy to wind (it's a tall toroid), compared to say E-cores or the like, or even just regular-height toroids.

Which isn't really a big problem winding by hand, and maybe that gives you some idea of how little it matters.

The material differences are typically fairly minor, in terms of being able to use something at all at least.  Whereas, if we were comparing say to laminated iron, or powdered iron, there will likely be functional differences: μ too low, or core losses too high to use at say ~100kHz.

The grossest difference between bead ferrites, would probably be if they are VHF+ range beads, i.e. impedance peak over 100MHz, which is achieved by using a low-μ material like #61 (\$\mu_r = 125\$), as opposed to medium-μ materials like #43, or high-μ like #31 or #77 (which can have an impedance peak as low as a few MHz).  This will be easy to determine based on the mechanical dimensions of the part and its impedance given some turns of a test winding.

The key point is, a ferrite bead might be intended for (optimized for, even) delivering loss (resistance) over a wide range of (high) frequencies, little is implied about losses at low frequencies.  A ferrite bead might have a peak impedance near 100MHz, and still be usefully (as a bead) lossy at 10MHz, but be a useful transformer in the 100s of kHz.

The other major difference is, saturation flux density may be relatively low.  Again, this isn't a massive difference, with most NiZn ferrites (lower μ, higher frequency range) saturating 0.2-0.3T, whereas most MnZn ferrites (most common type, medium to high μ, power frequency range) saturate at 0.3-0.4T.  The important difference here is, ferrite beads hardly use any flux density, so saturation is irrelevant for them, and materials tend to be more diverse (NiZn shows up more often); power ferrites (transformers, EMI chokes, gapped inductors, etc.) are almost exclusively MnZn.

To clarify the numbers, these "mixes" are Fair-Rite numbers (or clones thereof); see [Materials | Fair-Rite](https://fair-rite.com/materials/).  Other manufacturers have their own naming schemes, of course (e.g. compare Fair-Rite #95 to Ferroxcube 3C95, TDK PC95, etc.).

---

Mind, I have no idea if this at all suits any immediate need or project you might have in mind; you didn't mention any application.  Just offhand, cores of the size pictured will not be good for more than 10W or so; well below the power level where an engineer would opt for a forward converter in most cases.  But one can perform such experiments at any power level, so if you're just playing around, that's fine.

Comment: Thx for informations that’s hard to find. The transformer is not used for super-efficient converter. It’s for saving some energy that last in 100nF cap and putting this energy back to source. Otherwise i will have to waist it with resistor. The little losses ( damping) of core should even fits me to avoid oscilations when cap is discharging. The frequency is about 100khz.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is yes. But, of course, there are going to be some practical differences and limitations.

One of them is the **saturation magnetic flux**. Ferrites for EMI purposes tend to have lower saturation flux density, B<sub>sat</sub>. For example, TDK's N30 and T65 materials are quite popular (e.g. Snap-On clamp ferrites or single-piece toroidal beads). The frequency range is still similar to those popular for, say, power conversion (e.g. N87) but N30 saturates at ~250 mT whilst N87 saturates at above 400 mT.

The other is the **relative permeability**, µ (µ<sub>i</sub> or µ<sub>e</sub>), in general, and therefore A<sub>L</sub> factor for the same core shape. These tend to be much higher for EMI-targeted ferrites which allows you to wind less number of turns for the same inductance. But still keep the saturation flux density in mind. Also note that these ferrites will get really lossy above a certain frequency range.

The final one is the **curie temperature** (or curie point). This is, in simple terms, the temperature where the ferrite loses its properties (i.e. µ simply drops to zero). For general-purpose or power ferrites this is around 200 °C but for EMI ones expect something like 100~150 °C. This means that if your transformer gets lossy, which is quite likely, it's likely to lose its properties above certain level.

Comment: Thx. Just for make my understading correct, Do you mean the ferrite beads have higher relative permeability so higher inductance at the same turns? (Comparing to standard forward core.)

Comment: @MichalPodmanický generally yes. If you put airgap the inductance will become permeability-independent (i.e. µ disappears in equation) but for un-gapped (g = 0) inductors, if the core material is one of those for EMI (e.g. [N30](https://www.tdk-electronics.tdk.com/download/187204/fd7b13cb06de3e2edca6c617ac9de7da/pdf-n30.pdf) or [T65](https://www.tdk-electronics.tdk.com/download/528846/1598c89da613db594840e493e0ffb9fe/pdf-t65.pdf)) the inductance will be higher. This is what we expect from ferrite bead, isn't it? We want it to "resist" sudden current changes, hence "high-frequency filtering".

Comment: Thx, that make sense. I was probably unlucky with core I choosed for my application and didn’t suceed because i pick one from my scraps that is very light weight, i.e. low permeability and then low inductance.

Comment: It depends on the bead: we select material based on what frequency range we need. I don't get the supposed priority for high mu; #43 is probably the predominant material in use, a medium-mu NiZn. Perhaps you meant for CMCs? Those generally need the impedance peak to be very low (100s kHz even), so many turns and high mu are used.